# Can't query any data from sqlite - python

Tags: python, sqlite

**The problem**

I just created my first sqlite database and don't know anything about SQLite. It took over 2 days to make and during the process I was able to do run

```
connectioncursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM tracks""")
```

and see the data appear in idle.

Now that I finished, I wanted to look at the data but I am not returning any results. I don't know anything about SQLite to troubleshoot this. I don't know what to check, or how to check it. When I look online, I only see more examples for how to use SELECT but that wont help if I can't see any of the data I spent days trying to insert.

Here is the code:

```
import sqlite3

connecttosql = sqlite3.connect('musicdatabase.db')

connectioncursor = connecttosql.cursor()

connectioncursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM tracks""")
rows = connectioncursor.fetchone()

connecttosql.commit()
connecttosql.close()
```

Result

```
============ RESTART: \\VGMSTATION\testing scripts\sqlite test.py ============
>>> 
#in other words, nothing appears
```

The `musicdatabse.db` is in the same folder and it's 123 mb in size. I feel a little desperate as I just want to see the data I have worked days on trying to insert.

Is there any program, or any code, or any way that I can see my data?

Thank you for your time (also if I am missing something please let me know)

Comment: You're not printing `rows`... How would you expect something to appear?

Comment: Argh, I thought I saw a video saying that `fetchall` or `fetchone` does it automatically for you so you don't have to print it. That was easier than I thought. Thanks. I would like to give you the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer-ify my comment:

You're not printing `rows` (in an interactive `>>>` shell, it would get printed implicitly), so nothing appears.

As a shortcut, you can just call `execute` on the connection:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('musicdatabase.db')
cur = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM tracks LIMIT 1")
row = cur.fetchone()
print(row)
```

Since you're not modifying data, no need to `.commit()` (and `.close()` will be called automatically for you on program end anyway).

Comment: I love when its just me being stupid! Thank you again. I will accept you answer in 5 minutes (The website gives me a timmer before I can accept any answers). Thanks again!